# Makefile, rule for all rule patterns

Tags: makefile

#### Context

I am using the pattern rule

```
%.png: %.tex
    compile.sh $<
```

to generate png files from all available (changed) tex files.

#### Problem

What I do not get right is that I want to use `make all` to do that for all of them at once.

```
all: *.tex
    compile.sh $^
```

However, `$^` seems to be always replaced by all tex files and not only the changed ones (obviously, the Makefile does not really know about the connection to the png files).

#### Not working alternative

Using

```
all: *.png
    compile.sh $^
```

does not make sense when the png files do not exist yet, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there really some specific reason that you have to do them all with a single command?  Why can't you just have `all` depend on all the `.png` files?

```
%.png: %.tex
        compile.sh $<

TEXFILES := $(wildcard *.tex)
all: $(TEXFILES:.tex=.png)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.